# Getting different responses from postman vs. python API call

Tags: python, api, postman

I'm trying get the same data from an API call in Postman using Python.

The call is relatively simple. It uses Basic Authorization that only requires the API key being passes as the username, and a dynamic component: csv_key variable that is passed from earlier codes.

I was able to successfully made the request (status code 200), but the response from Python is different from the one in Postman. It's missing all key-value pairs except the firs two: id and description.

I'm getting this response from postman:
[response from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bIm9.png)

```
    {
    "id": "63c9c0927885bf003ecd3a1b",
    "description": "Streaming analytics",
    "download_url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/***-static/***.csv?GoogleAccessId=888211540537-r3m40kms2upicdr07e5rl2q67feg9loh%40developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=4070908800&Signature=WvuuKdddCFKjSNpst5n8yKFNR5qtC1m1o1mQZFWLHmKomJtc7npa6PbwfRoTj9FhIIqbta98VPOYKMGW89XaqXtITh15V%2Bf9opAD3BnuLjTzWC6X24RC5kMCZATXpp9DWi1Our061%2FdKlpUozi1ir7b8AwBWWf%2Bs8u5J6VoelvtEyiZIO4l%2FQdeJ26GqDLRgWElEMAlBE3TJo7m3UuE8gOQPsYBCwBSfLI1bTIytNOHZMUlWuVtMQxEHzUOujAp%2Fgqn1Q8TGGzy5GoeEmzw%2FD80xs%2BALjhT%2BxdiN9riG6%2BEcObrhPoudxl32jUhVH0EmGJwjgiJFQpz%2FLfKr86LrCQ%3D%3D",
    "error": "Cannot read property 'email' of undefined",
    "completed_at": "2023-01-19T22:13:39.219Z"
}
```

But I'm only getting the first two key-value pairs using a Python script of the same API call:

[response from Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNIVN.png)

```
 csv key: 63c9c0927885bf003ecd3a1b
 api url: https://api.eventive.org/temporary_exports/63c9c0927885bf003ecd3a1b
        <Response [200]>
        response:[{'id': '63c9c0927885bf003ecd3a1b', 'description': 'Streaming analytics'}]
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

My code for the Python script is:

```
import requests
import json

url_for_key = 'https://api.***.org/reports/streams?event_bucket=63279b48d8f8f1009209694f&start=1674111600000&end=1674198000000&tz=America%2FDenver'
api_key = '*************************'
header = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r1 = requests.get(url=url_for_key, auth=(api_key, ''))

csv_obj = [r1.json()]
csv_key = csv_obj[0]['temporary_export']
#print(csv_obj)
print(f'csv key: {csv_key}')



url_for_link = 'https://api.***.org/temporary_exports/{}'.format(csv_key)
print(f'api url: {url_for_link}')

r2 = requests.get(url=url_for_link, headers=header, auth=(api_key, ''))
print(r2)
print(f'response:{[r2.json()]}')
```

csv_key is the same as id. Could anyone help me understand what's going on?

Many thanks,

Comment: Are your headers identical? Also please post the responses as text instead of images

Comment: You need to provide more explanation for your python code, headers, and doesn't auth have to be `HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')`

Comment: @eatmeimadanish Found the API docs here. https://help.eventive.org/en/articles/1475819-api-resource-guide. No password needed for auth.

Comment: `auth` needs to be of TYPE `HTTPBasicAuth` not simply a tuple...

Comment: @NathanMcCoy headers are identical, and I added responses as code.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish yes, but only 'user' is needed for this api call requirement; status code is 200 so authorization is good

Answer (score 0):

I think am late. But may be this will answer your question:

To solve this issue, you could try to read the CSV response directly using the csv module in Python, or use a third-party library like pandas to read the CSV response into a data frame.

This should read the CSV response from the API into a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a row in the CSV response. You can then access the keys and values in each dictionary to get the data you need.

Here is an example using the csv module:

```
import requests
import csv

url_for_key = 'https://api.***.org/reports/streams?event_bucket=63279b48d8f8f1009209694f&start=1674111600000&end=1674198000000&tz=America%2FDenver'
api_key = '*************************'
header = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r1 = requests.get(url=url_for_key, auth=(api_key, ''))

csv_obj = r1.json()
csv_key = csv_obj['temporary_export']
print(f'csv key: {csv_key}')

url_for_link = f'https://api.***.org/temporary_exports/{csv_key}'
print(f'api url: {url_for_link}')

r2 = requests.get(url=url_for_link, headers=header, auth=(api_key, ''))

# Read the CSV response using the csv module
reader = csv.DictReader(r2.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True))
response = [row for row in reader]

print(response)
```

In your code, you are wrapping the response object from `r1.json()` and `r2.json()` in a list using brackets, `[r1.json()]` and `[r2.json()]`, which is not necessary. This is causing the response to be printed as a list of dictionaries, even though there is only one dictionary in the list.

In the updated code, I am directly accessing the dictionary returned by r2.json(), which should include all the key-value pairs returned by the API.

Additionally, in your code, you are not checking the response status code to see if the request was successful or not. You should always check the status code to ensure that the request was successful before attempting to parse the response.

It also uses the csv module to parse the CSV response, which is a more appropriate approach than trying to parse it as JSON.